# Sometimes wrong values coming in Simple Interest Program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, floating-point, scanf

I have written a basic simple program to calculate interest in C and here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {

    float  principal,rate,time,si;

    printf("Please Enter The Principal Value = \n\t");
    scanf("%f",&principal);
    printf("Please Enter The Rate =\n\t");
    scanf("%f",&rate);
    printf("Please Enter Time =\n\t");
    scanf("%f",&time);

    si=(principal*rate*time)/100;
    printf("The Simple Interest Is = \t%f",si);

     }
```

Now the problem is that whenever I enter small values, the result is correct but whenever I enter some large values which are inside FLOAT's limit, I get some another value for which the integral value matches but the decimal value doesnt match. I have created this program in Linux and tried the same thing in Turbo C in windows and C Free and same error comes up. I also tried initializing the values but no use.

Example of rogue values coming up -

```
Principal = 123456 , Rate = 1, Time =1
Principal = 4512 , Rate = 412, Time =12
```

and many more examples are there. Please solve this query of mine

Comment: What are the rogue values you're getting?

Comment: @Barmar When I try the first example given, I get a Simple Interest Of   =    1234.560059 whereas it should be     1234.56. As far as the second example is concerned I am getting simple interest as - 223073.281250 which should be 223073.28 only.

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for answering the question via that as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For floating point numbers computation, rounding is a common issue, for example, when I run your program with `Principal = 123456 , Rate = 1, Time = 1`, the result is `1234.560059`.

A simple improvement is to use `double` instead of `float`, it provides more precision, note that you should change `%f` in `scanf` accordingly to `%lf`:

```
double  principal,rate,time,si;

printf("Please Enter The Principal Value = \n\t");
scanf("%lf",&principal);
```

Using `double`, the result is `1234.560000`, however note that rounding still happens, just with more precision.

Comment: I know this will sound wierd but what if I don't want to use the Double? I already used the Double and it was giving the correct value but it takes more space in the memory as well [I know this sounds odd]. Also if the rounding off happens then why does other values give out correct values? For ex - Principal = 4500 Rate = 34 & time = 12, i am getting correct answer that is  18360.000000

Comment: I really doubt that the more space that `double` occupies is an issue in most programs. And rounding doesn't mean you get incorrect value every time.

Comment: Yea no problem with double as well. Thanks for answering :)

But doesn't that mean that I should use `DOUBLE` everytime instead of Float?

Comment: @PranavJituri Using float generally requires more detailed, time consuming, analysis of rounding error than for double, so it is not worth considering float unless there are going to be enough numbers for the extra memory to matter. Use float if, and only if, the space matters, and analysis shows it has good enough precision. On your earlier comment, some calculations, especially ones involving only relatively small integers, are exact in both float and double.